# In Puppet, can I realize a defined type for each element in an array?

Tags: arrays, puppet

After removing my variable names and everything extraneous for readability, my code comes down to this. I already set up a custom fact that returns an array of users that I need to set up some configuration files for. I'm trying to use a defined resource type and realize it with an array argument to do the configs for each user because Puppet lacks a basic `for` loop, so the code I have simplifies to this:

```
define modulename::pushconfigs{
  user {"$name":
    ensure    => present
    parameter => value
    parameter => value
    parameter => value
  }
}

modulename::setconfigs{$::userlist: }
# $::userlist is an array of users, in the form [user1 user2 user3...]
```

for a couple parameters. However, when I try to run it, it says `couldn't`[do configs]`for user user1 user2 user3`. In other words, it's realizing the defined type only once, and it's trying to do so for a user whose name is the concatenated array.

How can I instead realize the defined type for each one in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$::userlist is a string.

Its a fact, and facts are strings.

You need to turn it into an array before you can iterate over it.

If $::userlist = "user1,user2,user3"

```
$a_userlist=split($::userlist,',')
modulename::setconfigs{$a_userlist: }
```

Comment: For anyone reading this, the `split` command doesn't like quotes, so you have to say `split($variable,'delimiter')` with no quotes. It took me a while to realize that `split("$variable",'delimiter')` and `split("${variable}",'delimiter)` don't work.

Answer (score 1):

This should work...

```
define createuser{
    user { $name :
      ensure => present,
      group => "gp",
      home => "/home/$name",
      shell => "/bin/bash",
    }
}

$allusers = [ "user1", "user2", "user3", "user4" ]

createuser{$allusers:}
```